# Installing Matplotlib on Windows ERROR - cannot open include file 'ft2build.h'

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I am trying to install `matplotlib` using:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

However, I keep getting this error:

`- cannot open include file 'ft2build.h' no such file or directory`

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpKlk.png)

Comment: Please post your codes and errors.

Comment: On Windows, sometimes your environment is not configured correctly build packages. In such cases, try to get the whl file from here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Thanks MrFuppes,but what do I do with the whl file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+how+to+install+whl+file

Comment: You can install whl files with `pip install PATHTOFILE.whl`

Answer (score 2):

You are using python 3.8 for which no pre-built `whl` files are avialable on `pypi`, therefore your `pip` is attempting to build matplotlib from source. For this, you need to have downloaded and installed the dependencies of `matplotlib`. In this case, `ft2build.h` is missing which is part of the `freetype` library.

If you really want to build from source, there is a [script based solution](https://github.com/jbmohler/matplotlib-winbuild) from the matplotlib developers to download and install all neccessary dependencies.

---

Since you probably don't care about building from source (which can be quite some work on Windows), you should instead consider one of these options:

1. Install a python version other than 3.8, it is very new and therefore there is not always an official pre-built `whl` file for modules you want to use
2. As MrFuppes suggested, download `matplotlib‑3.2.0rc1‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl` from [this unofficial collection of whl files](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib) and do `pip install matplotlib‑3.2.0rc1‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl` in your cmd

Answer (score -2):

It is a bit unclear what your problem is. It may just be that you have some packages that are not compatible. To avoid this sort of issue I can recommend the use of Anaconda: [https://www.anaconda.com/](https://anaconda.org)

It will come with python and most basic libraries, including matplotlib. I can also recommend [seaborn](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/seaborn) for professional-looking plots that do not require much code.

Comment: Thanks Victor. I already have anaconda installed with python. However, I need to run python scripts separately in power BI, and therefore need to install it on my cmd